# Get all attributes of product?

Tags: attributes

For every product in my magento i have custom attributes like - food_taste, food_brand and many more. I use them for filtering my products in category view. But now i want when clients open the product to see attributes.

Example:
Brand: Royal Canin
Taste: Chicken
......
I try with some codes that i found here, but...

```
$productId = 52;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$attributes = $product->getAttributes();

foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {       
    $attributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
    $label = $attribute->getStoreLabel($product);   
    $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
    echo $attributeCode . '-' . $label . '-' . $value; echo "<br />";       
}
```

Can you help me to do that.

Thank you

Comment: wt issue are you facing.?

Comment: If i use the code UP, i receive not found 404 of product page

Comment: make sure that the id of the product is 52. I suppose you have copied the code from here http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-get-all-attributes-attribute-name-value-of-a-product/, so just to clear my doubt

Comment: ýou want to show all attribute in product view page

Comment: Yes, i want to show all attributes of product in product view page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will give all the attributes of a product on the vew page

```
$product_id = $_product->getId();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$attributes = $product->getAttributes();

foreach ($attributes as $attribute) { 
    if($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'zoo_spec_dog' || $attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'zoo_taste')      
    {
        $attributeLabel = $attribute->getFrontendLabel();
        $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
        echo $attributeLabel . '-' . $label . '-' . $value; echo "<br />";       
    }
}
```

Comment: i try, but receive magento page  - 404 error: Page not found.

Comment: the code of 404
<head>
<title>Error 404: Not Found</title>
<base href="http://www.cccccccccc.bg/errors/default/" />

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: I receive really all attributes... hmmm... i need to define my question...How to show only 5 of them?

Comment: you can use this to display selected attributes `if($attribute->getFrontendLabel() == 'Your attribute label'){// display logic}`

Comment: Please update your answer whit selected attributes. Thank you

Comment: what are your attributes.?

Comment: example - zoo_spec_dog, zoo_taste

Comment: Manashvi, you there?

Comment: check my updated ans

Comment: Thank you so much, Manashvi, you are a great frien. Only the $label doesn't show, but this is not problem. Thank you.

Comment: i've updated my answer to show the attribute label instead of the code, check it

Comment: If i want $attributeLabel to get <strong>?

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT: Thanks To Fabian for catching my mistake; answer adjusted accordingly"***

> i want when clients open the product to see attributes.

**You need to mark these attributes as "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" = "Yes"***

This can be done two ways.

1. In the admin panel:
   [image: Attribute edit settings]
2. Via setup script, using `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup::updateAttribute()` to set the `is_visible_on_front` value to `1`.

Comment: If I understand the question correct, it should be "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" (`is_visible_on_front`). "Used in Product Listing" just adds the attribute to the flat index so that it gets loaded in collections and *can* be used in product lists.

Comment: Absolutely correct, @fschmengler. This is what happens when one spends too much time evangelizing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show custom attribute value in product view page.

You can set that in admin panel itself.

Navigate to

> admin > catalog > manage attribute

Then set all your custom attribute `visible on product view page on frontend` value yes.

So now your custom attribute value will be automatically rendered in product view page.